# Domain A can get cookie of Domain B

Tags: spring-boot, cookies

Here is my SpringBoot website in screenshot.

The domain name of my website is hswcfc-ddme-reconciliation-web.sit.homecreditcfc.cn (I call it domain A), but when I open Chrome Devtool to check the cookie information,
I find there is some cookie information about domain hswcfc-sams-web.uat.homecredit.cn(I call it domain B).

I think A shoud only get cookie for its own domain or its top level domain. Why domain A can get the cookie for domain B?

[image]